# How can I get the running result when I run method on contract?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, truffle

I want to write a simple function to call the method on contract and get the running result,

### This is the contract code

```
function _evaluate(uint8[5] _uploads) internal returns (bytes32 resultId){

    resultId= keccak256(abi.encodePacked(now,  msg.sender));

    addressToid[msg.sender] = resultId;
    idToResult[resultId] = Result(msg.sender, r);
  }

function upload(uint8[5] _inputs) public returns ( bytes32 resultId) {

    return _evaluate(_inputs);
  }
```

### front end js codes

```
// DEE is the contract name
return this.DEE.deployed()
        .then((instance) => instance.upload(this.inputs,  {from: base.accounts[0]}))
        .then((r) => {
          this.message = "Transaction done"

          console.log(r);


          
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.error(e)
          this.message = "Transaction failed"
        })
```

but in fact, I found r returned is a ** transaction detail**, like,

> ```
> {tx: "0xa543fff3c3bac2268c0c94a21f6cf62faa8cf667defcd9fd8dcdbcf7669a4e58",
> ```
>
> receipt: {…}, logs: Array(0)}
> logs
> :
> []
> receipt
> :
> {transactionHash: "0xa543fff3c3bac2268c0c94a21f6cf62faa8cf667defcd9fd8dcdbcf7669a4e58",
> transactionIndex: 0, blockHash:
> "0x07d691308724c73025de2f346dc0d6bc4eb7e7de9871e29ea2c4d4e8fb8222bb",
> blockNumber: 20, gasUsed: 56460, …}
> tx
> :
> "0xa543fff3c3bac2268c0c94a21f6cf62faa8cf667defcd9fd8dcdbcf7669a4e58"
> **proto**
> :
> Object

There is no information about the id which should be returned included.

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got the solution from this Ethereum.StackExchange post:

> It is not currently possible to return values from functions which
> modify the blockchain. To receive a return value, you can mark
> read-only functions as "constant".
>
> For non-constant functions, the only way to "return" information is by
> using Solidity Events, which coalesce as LOG opcodes in the Ethereum
> Virtual Machine.

Source: [Taylor Gerring](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/43/taylor-gerring), [Apr 23, 2016 at 7:47 AM](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3285/how-to-get-return-values-when-a-non-view-function-is-called/3286#3286)

*N.B. - the answer has been updated at the original location to reflect changes in Solidity.*

Answer (score 0):

Specify "view" in the function definition:

```
function upload(uint8[5] _inputs) public view returns ( bytes32 resultId) {
    // do something here
    // save ad calculate
    return "123";
 }
```

Comment: no, you cannot, I did not include code to store data in the blockchain here, but it did `do something`

Comment: I just update the question to add more about contract codes

Comment: yes, since you are saving to storage variable, it becomes a transaction. Hence the function cannot 'return' the value.